# Webpacker recompiling in a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, tailwind-css, webpacker, wsl-2

i'm trying to get a *Rails 6* project up and running in development. I am using *webpacker 6* and *tailwindcss 2*. For some reason webpacker will start the Compiling process again after each successfull compilation as soon as i open the website. It seems that something is triggering the compiling again but i dont know what it is. I am using WSL 2 on a Windows environment.
When i run **bin/webpack-dev-server** for the first time in a terminal (without opening the website on a browser) i get the expected output and webpacker is just compiling everything as it should be (*only compiling once*)

**But** as soon as i go the local running website via my browser webpacker wont stop recompiling even though i didnt change anything in the code. This is my terminal output:

```
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
ℹ ｢wdm｣: assets by status 5.05 MiB [cached] 29 assets
asset manifest.json 3.56 KiB [emitted]
webpack 5.39.1 compiled successfully in 531 ms
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /packs/css/application-36e9b2b1.css
ℹ ｢wdm｣: assets by status 5.05 MiB [cached] 29 assets
asset manifest.json 3.56 KiB [emitted]
webpack 5.39.1 compiled successfully in 673 ms
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
ℹ ｢wdm｣: assets by status 5.05 MiB [cached] 29 assets
asset manifest.json 3.56 KiB [emitted]
webpack 5.39.1 compiled successfully in 502 ms
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /packs/css/application-36e9b2b1.css
ℹ ｢wdm｣: assets by status 5.05 MiB [cached] 29 assets
asset manifest.json 3.56 KiB [emitted]
webpack 5.39.1 compiled successfully in 551 ms
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
ℹ ｢wdm｣: assets by status 5.05 MiB [cached] 29 assets
asset manifest.json 3.56 KiB [emitted]
webpack 5.39.1 compiled successfully in 466 ms
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /packs/css/application-36e9b2b1.css
ℹ ｢wdm｣: assets by status 5.05 MiB [cached] 29 assets
asset manifest.json 3.56 KiB [emitted]
webpack 5.39.1 compiled successfully in 453 ms
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
```

How do i stop webpacker-dev-server from compiling all the time? Or what could be the reason to trigger the compiling again and again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**
In case anybody else will get this problem:

It seems that there was a problem with my bundler version. I had to uninstall my bundler and now just use the default one from rails. I also removed node_modules
`rm -rf node_modules` and reinstall them by running `yarn install`. That fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I have the same problem but your solution did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same. Tailwind was the cause for that in my case.

If you have something like `"./**/*.html.haml",` in the `content` property of the tailwind config, then change it to something more concrete, such as:

```js
  content: [
    "./app/views/**/*.html.erb",
    "./app/views/**/*.html.slim"
  ],
```